# iPad Air 2 keeps losing Continuity features, requiring restart

Tags: ios, ipad, continuity

I have an iPad Air 2 running iOS 10.3.2. What I've found is that after a while, the universal clipboard feature will stop working, and I won't see app icons from my other devices underneath the app switcher.

This is always fixed by restarting.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Any ideas as to how to fix it once and for all?

Comment: Yes, it happens to me on both my iPhone and iPad.  The only 'fix' I've found is to restart.  For years I've found the continuity feature a bit buggy and unreliable.

Comment: Someone on Apple Discussions said to try to turn Wifi and bluetooth on and then off instead of restarting.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the Continuity features are more reliable in iOS 11.